# Does it make sense to use `extra-source-files` required for tests?

Tags: haskell, cabal

.. as it seems `extra-source-files` is a package (i.e non-component) level field. The file to be included is some JSON format configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For example, [aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-2.1.1.0/aeson.cabal) uses that field to include test data.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if it would make sense to make it a component-level field as well, as in my case, only the test needs it, so it fits better to be within the test stanza rather than top level? (If I include it currently in the test stanza, it says `Warning: xxx.cabal Unknown field: "extra-source-files"`)